An example of Monotone Class Theorem
The monotone class theorem is a fundamental result in measure theory. It is also referred to as the Dynkin's system theorem, see Section 2.1 of [KS98].
MTC is an abstract theorem to apply. For my own exercise,
I wrote down the proof of the Problem 2.1.4 related to MTC below. Please let me know if there is any mistake or better way.
Definition
A collection $\mathcal{D}$ of subsets of a set $\Omega$ is called a Dynkin system if it satisfies the following properties:

$\Omega\in \mathcal{D}$.
$A, B\in \mathcal{D}$ and $A\subset B$ imply $B\setminus A\in \mathcal{D}$.
$\{A_n\}_{n\ge 1} \subset \mathcal{D}$ and $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$ for all $i\ge 1$ imply $\cup_{n\ge 1} A_n \in \mathcal{D}$.

Theorem
Let $\mathcal C$ be a collection of subsets of a set $\Omega$, which is closed under pairwise intersections. If $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin system containing $\mathcal C$, then $\mathcal D$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$. This theorem will be used frequently whenever we need to show that a certain property, known to hold for a collection of sets, also holds for the $\sigma$-algebra.
Example (Problem 2.1.4)
Let $X = \{X_t: 0\le t <\infty\}$ be a stochastic process for which $X_0, X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}, \ldots, X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}$ are independent random variables for all $0= t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n < \infty$. Then, for any fixed $0\le s < t < \infty$, the increment $X_t- X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s^X$.
Proof
If $T= \{t_1, t_2, \ldots t_m\}$ be a finite subset of $[0, s]$, then we will denote $X_T= [X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \ldots, X_{t_m}]$ for a vector of random variables. Let $\mathcal C$ be the union of all $\sigma(X_T)$ over all finite subsets $T$ of $[0, s]$. Meanwhile, let $\mathcal D$ be the collection of all events $A$ such that $A \perp \sigma(X_t- X_s)$.

Let $A_i \in \sigma (X_{T_i})$ for $i=1, 2$. Then, we have $A_1 \cap A_2 \in \sigma(X_{T_1}, X_{T_2}) = \sigma(X_{T_1 \cup T_2}) \subset \mathcal{C}$. Then, $A_1 = \{X_{t_1}\in B_1, X_{t_2}\in B_2, \ldots, X_{t_m}\in B_m\}$ Hence, $\mathcal C$ is closed under pairwise intersections.
Next, we need to show that $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin system. This follows from the following properties:

$\Omega\perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$.
Let $A_1, A_2 \perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$ and $A_1\subset A_2$. Then, $ A_2 \setminus A_1  \perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$.
Let $A_i \perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$ and $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$ for all $i\ge 1$. Then, $\cup_{n\ge 1} A_n \perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$.


The last piece is to show that $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal D$. Let $A\in \sigma (X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_m})$ for some $0\le t_1\le \ldots \le t_m\le s$. Note that there exists an obvious choice of continuous function $F$ such that $[X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_m}] = F(X_{t_0}, X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}, \ldots, X_{t_m}-X_{t_{m-1}})$. Therefore, $A \perp \sigma(X_t - X_s)$.

By the monotone class theorem, we have $\mathcal F_s^X = \sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \mathcal D$, which implies that $X_t - X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s^X$.

Looks fine.
A little simpler would be to take $\mathcal C$ to be the collection of all events of the form $\cap_{k=1}^n{X_{t_k}\in B_k}$, with $0\le t_t\le \cdots\le t_n\le s$. Clearly $\mathcal C$ is closed under intersections and generates $\mathcal F_s^X$ and (as you argue) is a subset of $\mathcal D$.

@Snoop Yes, essentially the same. I did not realize there is one.

@JohnDawkins Agreed. Thanks.
